# Change UITextView height according to screen size

Tags: uitextview, autolayout, iphone-5

I am trying to change the height of my textview through code when the 4 inch screen is detected. Unfortunately I cant get my current code to work. Can anyone see what is wrong? Both ways its written it doesn't work. In the code I show both ways I've tried. I have this written in viewDidLoad method too.

If this cannot be worked out then can anyone help me out to set height attribute value in attribute inspector for both the screens (with height 568 and 480)

my code,
`if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)

 {
        [myTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 78.0f, 280.0f, 415.0f)];
    }`

Comment: have a look to this Question.<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652598/cant-change-uitextview-frame-size-programatically

Comment: your condition is perfect and works correctly please double check all the things and make sure you give proper referencing and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

uncheck 'use autolayout' from interface builder and use 'autosizing' from interface builder to resize your textview height

Comment: I am using autolayout throughout the project, cant untick that option !

Comment: Thanks man !!! You saved my day. My code was always correct but due to autolayout it was not working.